# Country wise effects of sanctions on country's economic parameters

Tags: reference-request, sanctions

The Ukraine war and the following sweeping sanctions are generally considered quite unprecedented and are having far reaching consequences.

I am looking for ordered detailed corralled data on this.

There is this personal vlog series [Joe Blogs](https://www.youtube.com/c/JoeBlogs/) giving the effects on the economies of various countries

For example:
[Tunisa](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4gKiodydUSo)
[Sri Lanka](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=alMKCkFZzjw)
[Peru](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GmTtwc7cVC8)

He also has things like this
[Topic wise:Hunger, fertilizer, finance](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oZIfSxD-BYk)

But I dont want news/blogs/twitter etc.
I am looking for worldwide systematic authoritative data re macro parameters like output, GDP, inflation on this. eg UN/IMF published data.
[I did look before asking]